# Apache Beam on Dataflow - Load external file

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running an Apache Beam ETL job on Dataflow from a template I created. I want to add an additional step where I upload the processed data to BigQuery and create the table if needed, so I need to declare the table schema.

The schema is actually pretty large, so maybe the best option is to write it on a .json file and import it with a simple:

```
with open('filename.json', 'r') as f:
    schema = json.load(f)
```

However, how can I declare this external file on my template so that when the job gets deployed and run on the workers they can find the file? Can I set any option like that on my `setup.py` so that the file gets saved with the template?

Other alternatives I have thought are:

1. Saving the file to a GCS bucket and reading it using the cloud storage client and pass it to my functions as a side input
2. Writing the schema manually on my pipeline file, even if it gets dirty

What would be the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For big files I would store in a GCS bucket (Alternative 1). If this is not applicable you can create [a flex template for your pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#python_only_creating_and_building_a_container_image) and add the schema to the container.